# Django ORM equivalent for 'or'?

Tags: python, sql, django, orm, django-orm

I need to do this in django orm.

```
SELECT * FROM offer WHERE country_id = 1 OR mundial = 1;
```

How do I do the 'OR' in django like:

```
list = offer.objects.filter(country_id=1, #HOW DO I PUT 'OR' HERE?)
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Q`:

```
from django.db.models import Q
list = offer.objects.filter(Q(country_id=1) | Q(something_else=1))
```